# "Windows can't open this file" when downloading torrent with Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, download, bittorrent, file-association

Previously when I was clicking on a "get this torrent" button in Chrome, it would just download the `.torrent` file. That is the expected behaviour.
Someday, probably surfing too late and too tired, I did associate `.torrent` to notepad.
To clear up the mess, I opened regedit, searched for "torrent" and deleted any nodes I found.
Now, in Chrome, whenever I click to download a torrent, I get this "Windows can't open this file" dialog.
I tried using IE instead, but IE opens the torrent file in the browser, not better.
How can I restore the default behaviour, to just download the file to the "Downloads" folder ?
Note: I do NOT want to associate any program to those files, since I transfer them to a folder on my NAS, which then thakes care of the download.
Thanks !

Comment: [You do it the same was as always](http://www.howtogeek.com/171932/how-do-you-remove-a-default-file-association-in-windows-7/).  The downvote was issued because of [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=delete+file+assosication&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#channel=fflb&q=delete+file+association&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&spell=1)

Comment: @Ramhound: open your eyes and read the question. I already did that (paragraph 4)

Comment: **Check Again.**  Your question is also one giant paragraph